# Java List : initial size

Tags: java, list, optimization

Which way is better for initializing a Java List:

- `new ArrayList<String>(futureSize)`
- `new ArrayList<String>(futureSize + 1)`

(in order to prevent resizing of the list)

`futureSize` is the future size of the list once filled.

*Note : If you are going to comment/answer anything about "premature optimizaton is...", "you should instead...", **PLEASE DON'T**. I am looking for an answer to my question, that's all.*

Comment: If you're concerned about the answer quality, maybe you should explain a bit more about your set up. Why do you think it's important to opimise there? What have you done to come to the conclusion that list initialisation is part of the problem, etc...

Comment: @Lukas no I don't want to. If you ask how to build a website with PHP, why would you have to explain why you want a website, why with PHP, why do you want it red or blue or with glittering stars everywhere. I am just looking for an answer for this simple, clear question...

Comment: It's the eternal question of misunderstanding on this platform... :-) You're the one that's fighting and getting angry. You got three good and correct answers for your question and you didn't want to hear one additional word... Then you better look into the code and not discuss, because apparently that makes you angry... So be it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see from the implementation of `add(E e)` and (similar methods)

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacity(size + 1);
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

... that you should not run into trouble (i.e. the internal array is not resized) if you use

```
new ArrayList<String>(futureSize)
```

Comment: I'm not wondering if I'll run into problems, I just don't want the list to be resized. With the code you've given, I can assume then that `futureSize + 1` is better, because it will prevent any resizing ?

Comment: By problems I meant resizing of the list. When you add the last element to the list, then `size == futureSize - 1` at the time `ensureCapacity` is called. So you won't run into problems == the list won't be resized

Answer (score 3):

I'd say `futureSize` is OK, although I also think that your application's performance won't depend on that optimization, unless you actually have proved with load tests and profiling that your bottleneck is array initialization.

And if you've done that, then it is much quicker to just try both variants and compare the results.

Comment: I think in this case, using common sense is more effective than setting up a meaningful load-test...

Comment: This is too complicated for me to compare the results, this is why I am asking for professionals that can answer me directly. And I need to optimise a part of code, why would I not try to optimise that as much as I can (this is such an easy modification). Even in theory, I find this question (and future answer) interesting, just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Matthieu The actual bottlenecks in code tend to be SQL queries without an index, file reading etc and not Java code's operations within memory, so this sort of micro-optimization is usually not needed. You are right though, that this is an optimization which is easy to make every time, but in my experience sweating over this stuff is not worth it. Focus on writing quality code which can be easily maintained and fix performance issues when they arise.

Comment: @Lukas, @deltaforce2 you are not answering my question, I'm not looking for these kind of advices, please let me get my answer and let me do what I want. Thanks (nothing personnal, it's just extremly hard to have an answer about optimization on Stack Overflow, I always have to fight with those kind of answers)

Comment: Well, the point in specifying the initial list size is not the initialization cost. It is avoiding the many copies from a smaller array into a bigger array each time the inner array must be expanded to fit additional elements. If you know the final size in advance, it doesn't harm to state it. I vote also for `futureSize`, this is what javadoc says.

Comment: @Matthieu I stand by my choice, `futureSize` is OK. It is easier to write and to read and performs like a charm. If you don't believe me, I dare you to write a test program and see how it works out (make sure to post the results here) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use the apache commons FixedSizeList class

Here's the link:
[Apache Commons FizedSizeList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/FixedSizeList.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea, but I need to stick for the original list types. +1 though

Answer (score 2):

By quoting the javadoc:

> ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
>
> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

Therefore, `futureSize` should be what you use. Plain simply.

Answer (score 0):

`new ArrayList<String>(futureSize)`

Is the better way.
As it is not good practice to have memory more then requirements.
And about list if re-sizing is the problem, then figure out proper deviation of resizing to make it like

```
new ArrayList<String>(futureSize+probableDeviation)
```

Insertion of just 1 more element will not solve problem, so it would be better to use first one without deviation.